# Giving json to Autocomplete JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have the following javascript,php (idf is an inputbox in html):

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
// tell the autocomplete function to get its data from our php script
$('#idf').autocomplete({
    source: "../php/testingauto.php"
});});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
session_start();
try{
    $q =$conn->query("SELECT ID_farm FROM farm");
    $result=$q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($result)!=0) {
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

And I want to give my JSON result in the auto-complete list. 
But I always get a null result on the output of the auto-complete function.
Am I doing something wrong ?

This is the JSON I get from echo: `[{"ID_farm":"CYS1000004"},{"ID_farm":"CYS1021009"}]`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the autocomplete function defined?

Comment: @LajosArpad is a JQuery method 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: i use the above libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to render correct format from the resource response like the availabletags example, Hope it helps :)